# Java associate data with current thread

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on web application, which is deployed on apache tomcat web server. I want to associate data with current thread of http request. For this purpose I have created following class:

```
public class ThreadData {

    private static final Map<Long, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<>();

    public static Map<String, String> getDataMap(long threadId) {
        if (data.get(threadId) == null) {
            data.put(threadId, new HashMap<String, String>());
        }

        return data.get(threadId);
    }

    public static void put(String key, String value) {
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        getDataMap(threadId).put(key, value);
    }

    public static String get(String key) {
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return getDataMap(threadId).get(key);
    }
}
```

I want to know if such kind of solution is right and safe for this problem .

Comment: Have you looked into [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)?

Comment: If you want it associated with a single thread, why are you using a `static final Map`?

Comment: FYI:  Each request **is** a single thread of execution, so the data should only exist for the scope of the request.  Are you sure you want that, or do you want it scoped to a session?

Comment: There is also thread pool. Expect the same ids in your logic.

Comment: @MadConan With each http request comes certain amount of data, which I have to pass to some layers of code. I don't want to pass this data as function arguments, because each layer of code needs only part of this data. So I thought it will be good idea to associate this data with current thread in centralized location and then access them from appropriate layers. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is covered by `ThreadLocal` class, in your case it would be

```
ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> data = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> initialValue() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
};
```

If you still want to use `put` or `get`, you may define them in such a way:

```
public static void put(String key, String value) {
    data.get().put(key, value);
}

public static String get(String key) {
    return data.get().get(key);
}
```